# Different sidebars for different pages on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, widget, sidebar

I'm trying to design a theme on WordPress (version 3.3.2) but I am having a few problems in having the sidebar display a different set of widgets on certain pages.

I have tried several online tutorials and this one in particular http://www.rvoodoo.com/projects/wordpress/wordpress-tip-different-sidebars-on-different-pages/ but unfortunately there is no change in the sidebar when I move to a different page

I registered two sidebars on my *functions.php* as shown below, one which I would consider as main, and the other as a custom sidebar, and I also added different widgets to these sidebars.

```
<?php register_sidebar( //register sidebar
    array(
        'name' => 'Right-side',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="rightwidget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
        ));


        register_sidebar( //register second sidebar
    array(
        'name' => 'Second-right',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="rightwidget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
        ));

?>
```

Following that, I created the files *sidebar.php* and *sidebar-second.php* to be able to call them.

*sidebar.php*

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Right-side')) : ?>
        <h3 class="widget-title">No widget added</h3>
        <p> Please add some widgets</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!--ends sidebar-->
```

*sidebar-second.php*

```
 <div id="sidebar">
    <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Second-right')) : ?>
        <h3 class="widget-title">No widget added</h3>
        <p> Please add some widgets</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!--ends sidebar-->
```

And then I added replace my `<?php get_sidebar() ; ?>` statement with following conditional

```
<?php if( is_page('225') ) : ?>
<?php dynamic_sidebar('second'); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_sidebar() ; ?>
<?php endif ; ?>
```

However only the widgets added to the *sidebar.php* are displayed on every page. Any help on how I could change this, or pointers on what I could be doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that your code is trying to find a page with the _slug_ "225" rather than the id 225. Try removing the quotes from around 225 and see if that works.

Comment: I just tried that and its still the same result.

Comment: Have you done some debugging to make sure that you are on the page that you think that you are? For example, `<?php echo $post->ID ?>` and make sure that prints out "225"?

Comment: I just ran the code and noticed that it prints out a number for each blog post, not 225 as it indicates on the address bar. I've also noticed that the sidebar changes when it is applied to other pages but not on this one. Please note that the page in question is my blog page

Comment: Do you mean that this is a blog directory page, like index.php or archive.php? Or is this a specific blog post?

Comment: I seem to have run the code within the loop, which is why it is giving my the id for each blog post. I just tried the code outside the loop and it prints out 1 instead.

Comment: Yes it is the blog directory page (index.php).

Comment: Okay. You want the alternative sidebar on ONLY the blog index page, then you can ditch the if clause and call `get_sidebar('second')` directly in the index page _provided you have separate single.php and/or page.php files for displaying posts and pages_

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you! the other pages now have a different sidebar. I really appreciate this. Any ideas as to why the other method didn't work?

Comment: No problem. I encountered the very same issue not to long ago. If I was able to help, please upvote or accept my answer. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like you are using `<?php dynamic_sidebar('second'); ?>` where you should be using `<?php get-sidebar('second'); ?>`

What get_sidebar('foo') does is look for a file named 'sidebar-foo.php' in the root directory of your theme and includes it. dynamic_sidebar('bar'), on the other hand, looks for a sidebar registered with:

```
<?php register_sidebar( array( 'name' => 'bar' ... ) ) ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just changed `<?php dynamic_sidebar('second') ; ?>` to `<?php get_sidebar('second') ; ?>` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [Custom Sidebar Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-sidebars/)?

It's really easy to use and does not need any coding

Answer (score 0):

You have two sidebars. when you want to use the sidebar-second file on a particular page, instead of calling

```
<?php get_sidebar('second') ; ?>
```

TRY

```
<?php get_sidebar('sidebar-second.php') ; ?>
```

this should do the trick

Comment: tried to format the code, not entirely certain if that's what you intended, please review - and correct, if needed - the edit :-)